# Category sort order for different stores

Tags: multistore, sorting, category-tree

We want to change the order of categories so they are different in our stores but every time we change the order in say the FRENCH store, the UK store is also changed.

Looking at the database it seems there is one table which powers the sort order. catalog_category_entity

Can this not be done for stores sharing the one default category tree?

We have used the 3rd party software emagicone for doing mass updates in the past and there is a discussion about this being an issue here http://www.novusweb.com/1622/e-commerce-technology/fixing-magento-category-order-problems/ but we definitely have the 'position' set on each category with a number and the table catalog_category_entity confirms this.

Comment: do you want to change the order of category in menu? or product sorting in category page?

Answer (score 4):

Any need for reorganization of categories in different store scopes means that you have to duplicate your categories under distinct root categories. Sorry - it's a limitation to Magento's tree modeling of the categories which ultimately resolves (as you noticed) to the global-scope sorting attribute on the entity table.

Comment: Hi benmarks, Is there any options to do that? Do you know If there is any module that resolve that functionalitu? or is a part of Magento that is better not to modify, in the development point of view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using custom attribute. in Magento 2. I think same could be done in M1.

1. Add new product attribute with seting "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to Yes.
   Add new attribute to your attribute set.
2. Assing numbers for products.
3. Catalog => Categories => choice Category => change store view, and change "Available Product Listing Sort By" and "Default Product Listing Sort By" to use your attribute.